# How to force chmod 777 on readonly usb

Tags: usb

This happens often where i cannot write to my flasdrive, then I must format the thing. 
I do not know why this happens either, can it be prevented?
How can I force chmod 777 on the drive so I can copy files to it?

any help and advise please?
thanks

Comment: This question is not programming related.

Comment: should it always be? that is why i tagged it in usb. how should i have tagged it or should i not ask such questions in the first place?

Comment: See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can ask your question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or even better on [UNIX](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: did not know, reposted it there

Comment: Stack overflow is not just programming, I consider it generalized.  For specialist areas we do have dedicated sub forums but SO is the hub in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

well try it as:

```
chmod -rf 777
```

or if this doesn't work try:

```
sudo chmod -rf 777
```

Edit:

on some Unix distributions it you can do it as:

```
chmod -f 777
sudo chmod -f 777
```

Comment: i did try the above but still to no avail :(

Comment: chmod -f 777 worked for me. -r was not recognized on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mac, open Finder and go to the file. Then right click and select Get Info. Next, UNCHECK the box that says LOCKED (you may need to click on the padlock and enter your password first). Once that's done, you can chmod at will.